# overcommit_memory and overcommit_ratio

Tags: linux, kernel, memory, virtual-memory

Here is my current setting:

```
vm.overcommit_ratio = 50 (default)
vm.overcommit_memory = 2
```

And Current Memory Usage:

```
[localhost~]$ free -g
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:            47         46          0          0          0         45
-/+ buffers/cache:          1         45
Swap:           47          0         47
```

As per the [documentation](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/4/html/Reference_Guide/s3-proc-sys-vm.html) what I understood is:

`vm.overcommit_memory = 2` will not allow to overcommit memory than 50 % of RAM `(as vm.overcommit_ratio is 50)` but still I can see that current memory usage is 46 GB out of 47 GB.

Did I misunderstood anything?

Comment: you added this to `/etc/sysctl.conf`and run `sysctl -p` and verified the settings with `sysctl -a` right?

Comment: 46 GB out of 94 GB doesn't seem like anything has been committed _over_. Though I don't think `free` can show you how much virtual memory has been allocated, anyway.

Answer (score 7):

Actually, setting vm.overcommit_memory=2 DOES allow overcommit. If you set overcommit_ratio to (say) 200, then memory can be committed to the extent of swap +(RAM * 200/100).

The kernel documentation is slightly misleading in implying that '2' means don't overcommit - it means commit to this limit, which in the case of overcommit_ratio (and that's a misnomer as it's really a percentage) being greater than 100, does allow for overcommit.

vm.overcommit_memory is more accurately described as setting a limit to overcommit, which *by default* doesn't allow any overcommit.

You can see the commit limit:

```
    $free -m | awk '$1 ~/[Mm]em/ {print $2}' ; sysctl -a 2>/dev/null | grep vm.over  ; grep -i commitlimit /proc/meminfo


vm.overcommit_kbytes = 0
vm.overcommit_memory = 2
vm.overcommit_ratio = 800
CommitLimit:    23449596 kB
```

Answer (score 1):

The `vm.overcommit_*` settings control userspace memory allocation. They have no effect on the memory the kernel can allocate.
Additionally the value you are taking 50% of is physical memory + swap. 47+47=94. So userspace can allocate up to 47gb.

Your `free` output shows you have 1gb used by userspace, and 45gb used by the kernel for caching. 1gb userspace is well under 50% of 94gb.

---

Additional correction:

> `vm.overcommit_memory = 2` will not allow to overcommit memory than 50 % of RAM

This setting will not allow overcommit **at all**. Combined with `vm.overcommit_ratio=50`, it will allow userspace to commit up to 50% of total memory. "commit" != "overcommit"